# I want to redirect according to pate-variable in the URL, how do I do that in PHP?

Tags: php, redirect, switch-statement

I have a URL which includes a variable, and I want that variable to determine which page to redirect to. I have tried using Meta-redirect in a Switch statement, but it doesn't work. What I am doing wrong?

```
<?php
setcookie("affiliate", $_GET['a'], time()+31536000);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>

<?php
switch($_GET['p'])
{
case"h": 
echo "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=website/">";
echo "redirecting in 1 second";
echo "if this page does not redirect <a href="website/">click here.</a>";
  break;

case"w":
echo "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=website/watches.html">";
echo "redirecting in 1 second";
echo "if this page does not redirect <a href="website/watches.html">click here.</a>";
  break;

case"sf":
echo "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=website/watches/solar-flare.html">";
echo "redirecting in 1 second";
echo "if this page does not redirect <a href="website/watches/solar-flare.html">click here.</a>";
  break;

default:
echo "incorrect page option";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

thanks :)

Chris

Answer (score 0):

use the `header` function:

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

or

```
header('Location: http://google.com');
```

instead of printing meta tags.

NOTE: The `header` function must be used BEFORE printing anything on the page. So i suggest you to move your switch at the top of your code.

Comment: thanks, but I don't think that does what I need. I NEED the viewer to see the message for 1 second, then the pages redirects, and the manual link needs to be a different one for each variable option.

Comment: Okay, no problem, then you should print the meta tag inside de head tag. the switch could be there. And for every case you can declare a $messageForUser and print the message correctly in the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `refresh=X;url=Y` header for redirect after X seconds:

```
<?php
setcookie("affiliate", $_GET['a'], time()+31536000);

switch($_GET['p']) {
    case"h": 
        header("refresh:5;url=website/"); 
        $body = "redirecting in 1 second<br />" . "if this page does not redirect <a href=\"website/\">click here.</a>";
        break;

    case"w":
        header("refresh:5;url=website/watches.html"); 
        $body = "redirecting in 1 second<br />" . "if this page does not redirect <a href=\"website/watches.html\">click here.</a>";
        break;

    case"sf":
        header("refresh:5;url=website/watches/solar-flare.html"); 
        $body = "redirecting in 1 second<br />" . "if this page does not redirect <a href=\"website/watches/solar-flare.html\">click here.</a>";
        break;

    default:
        $body = "incorrect page option";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>

    <?= $body ?>

</body>
</html>
```